# async upload not working when not logged

Tags: php, uploads

I use this code to upload file from the front end.

```js
formData = new FormData;
formData.append('action', 'upload-attachment');
fileInputElement = document.getElementById('file');
formData.append('async-upload', fileInputElement.files[0]);
formData.append('name', fileInputElement.files[0].name);
formData.append('type', fileInputElement.files[0].type);
my_nonce = document.getElementById('my_nonce').value;
formData.append('_wpnonce', my_nonce);

axios.post('/wp-admin/async-upload.php', formData, {
    headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
}).then(function(response) {
    infos_contact.file_uploaded = response.data.data.filename;
    infos_contact.file_uploaded_url = response.data.data.url;
})["catch"](function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

It's working fine when logged in, but not when I'm not logged. Since it's for the frontend, it's useless if it doesn't work when not logged. I guess WordPress protect the upload function if you're not logged in for security reason.

Can I use a hook to bypass this protection?

Thanks!

Comment: What hook are you using to run this currently? If you're using [`wp_ajax_{$action}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax_action/), then you'd need to also hook it to [`wp_ajax_nopriv_{$action}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax_nopriv_action/) to have the action run for non-authenticated users.

Comment: I don't use any hook, that's the thing, I'm using the default upload-attachment action.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change /wp-admin/async-upload.php to /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php to make the hook work.